# TeamCity 10 Plugin: Add message to build log

Tags: java, plugins, teamcity

I'm developing plugin for TeamCity 10.

I have created Listener to do something during build:

```
public class XYZBuidListener extends BuildServerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void buildFinished(@NotNull SRunningBuild build) {
        Loggers.SERVER.info("FINISHED");
        sendNotification(build);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildStarted(@NotNull SRunningBuild build) {
        Loggers.SERVER.info("STARTED");
        sendNotification(build);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildInterrupted(@NotNull SRunningBuild build) {
        Loggers.SERVER.info("Interrupted");
        sendNotification(build);
    }
}
```

On each event I'd like to write something into Build Log tab. Unfortunetly nothing that I have tried worked. E.g I tried to write something as error message:

```
build.getBuildLog().getErrorMessages().add(new LogMessage(...))
```

Just to avoid confusion - this is what I've meant as "Build Log tab"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TeamCity plugin model makes heavy use of Spring beans. Have a look at how other plugins are implemented, for example the SinCity plugin (disclaimer: I'm the author), specifically:

- the [server listener](https://github.com/sferencik/SinCity/blob/master/sin-city-server/src/main/java/sferencik/teamcity/sincity/autoTrigger/BuildStatusListener.java)
- the [autowire config](https://github.com/sferencik/SinCity/blob/master/sin-city-server/src/main/resources/META-INF/build-server-plugin-sin-city.xml)

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have checked alot of plugins (hipchat,slack, commit etc) and noone of them logs message to Build Log. Unfortunately I do not see that in your plugin too.

Comment: [ClutterStats](https://github.com/sferencik/ClutterStats/blob/master/clutter-stats-agent/src/main/java/sferencik/teamcity/clutterstats/BuildStatusListener.java) does. (Also mine.) But please note this is happening in an *agent*-side plugin, not a *server*-side one.